# Transactions using mysql_real_escape_string

Tags: php, performance, mysql-real-escape-string

Working with MySQL lately, from PHP, I am wondering about this:

- What is the performance impact by using `mysql_real_escape_string()` multiple times at a script?
- Is it worth to try to reduce the number of calls to this function for a given script?
- Does it determines the character set of the connection each time is called, or this value is cached?

If a scenario is needed, I'm thinking about PHP, and distinction between text and numbers, where numbers (using `intval()`, `floatval()` or direct casts) can be included without a call.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Don't be penny-wise and pound-foolish.**

Your questions are in the realm of micro-optimizations.  Creating a needed index or caching some query result will have an order of magnitude more benefit than worrying about the performance impact of a few calls to `mysql_real_escape_string()`.

By the way, typecasting with `(int) $variable` is slightly faster than calling `intval($variable)`.  But this too would be a micro-optimization.

Answer (score 2):

If you need to escape user input prior to database entry then you will have to use `mysql_real_escape_string()` ... don't worry too much about premature optimization.

Alternatively, you can look into prepared statements which will save you having to call this function multiple times - and it is more secure as it separates SQL logic from user input altogether.